Using a platinum loop to light a gas stove in Oliver Sacks's memoir
In Oliver Sacks's memoir Uncle Tungsten, he writes "I badgered my parents constantly with questions … Why did my mother use the platinum loop that hung above the stove to cause the gas burner to catch fire?" (page 5 in the 2001 Borzoi edition)
This would have been in the 1930's, at a time when I thought all gas stoves would have had pilot lights. Closing the pilot lights is economical, but I always assumed that one would want a lit match handy when turning on the gas to a burner! Was this some sort of alternative, and if so, how did it work?

I suspect that Sacks is describing a device sometimes known as platinum "gas match", or more precisely, a catalytic gas igniter. It has been known since the 1820s that platinum has a catalytic action that can cause hydrogen to combust in air when passed over a platinum mesh (the mesh structure is needed to give the platinum metal a large surface area). This was the physical principle behind Dobereiner's lighter, used to ignite a stream of hydrogen to provide a light source.
The same principle was used in the 1930s and 1940's to produce a gas lighter, which did not depend on an open flame, or the piezoelectric lighters that we commonly use today. A small amount of finely divided platinum was coated onto a filament, and this filament was attached to a looped handle to enable the filament to be held in the gas stream without burning the user. Here is a picture of one from England, the "New Lytic Gas Match":

The large loop on the right is the handle, and the platinum coated wire is inside the spiral on the left.
Although the platinum was only found on a small part of the object, I can certainly imagine a small child calling such an item "a platinum loop". Sacks actually describes the catalytic action of platinum later in the book in chapter 11 ("Humphrey Davy: a poet-chemist"):

[Humphrey Davy] discovered the miracle of catalysis... Thus, for
instance, the platinum loop we kept above the kitchen stove would glow
when put in the stream of gas, and, becoming red-hot, ignite it. This
principle of catalysis was to become indispensable in thousands of
industrial processes.


Well, I learned something new. :-D

https://www.reddit.com/r/videos/comments/a93iv1/interesting_1930s_lighter_uses_platinum_catalytic/ for a video showing the operation of a platinum catalyst lighter.

also the murder weapon in The Dust of Death by Asimov :)

It's worth noting that the gas is question wouldn't have been methane (as today) but town gas (coal gas), a mixture of carbon monoxide (CO) and hydrogen (H₂).  While platinum is an interesting catalyst in methane chemistry, its use for ignition like this relies on free hydrogen

@SeanDuggan: direct youtube link https://youtu.be/SF1UmiwkIJM?si=HPN0RywV7qX-Kdls

@ChrisH Interestingly it also works with methanol vapor - see SeanDuggan's video.

Methanol is basically the same thing as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methanol: "Carbon monoxide and hydrogen react over a catalyst to produce methanol."

Wonderful!
And now I'll have to go read The Dust of Death!

Does it reduce the auto-ignition temperature of hydrogen (or town gas) to below room temperature?

@CSM For pure hydrogen it reduces it significantly below room temperature (I believe the lowest recorded temperature for it is almost -200 degrees Celsius, though that would require a much more optimally designed catalyst). And at the point at which the hydrogen is burning, the effects of the platinum become largely irrelevant for starting town gas because the adiabatic flame temperature of hydrogen in air is almost four times the auto-ignition temperature of carbon monoxide.
